# Copying title style

Tags: titles, article

I want to know how to have the same title/author and section style as this [(link)](http://web.tiscali.it/ladepie/oldandnew1998.pdf)

I tried with `book` document class and

```
\chapter*{...} 

[...]

\section{..}
```

but it's not the same thing.

Comment: It looks like a local formating.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost what you want

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}
\part*{Old and New on the Schwarzian Derivative}
\section*{\LARGE Brad Osgood}
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution... please try to be more specific...

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[latin]{babel} % demo only
\usepackage{lipsum} % demo only

\usepackage{setspace}

\linespread{1.1}

\begin{document}
{\noindent\bfseries\Huge\parbox{11cm}{\flushleft Old and New on the Schwarzian Derivative}}

\vskip14pt

{\noindent\bfseries\LARGE\parbox{11cm}{\flushleft Brad Osgood}}

\vskip24pt

\section{Introduction}

\noindent\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```